# Semantic UI Form Validator doesn't block request when form submit with Enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    fields: {
       term: ['minLength[5]', 'empty']
    }
});

$.fn.api.settings.api = {
   'search': '_endpoint/check.php'
};

$('#form').api({
   action: 'search',
   method: 'POST',
   serializeForm: true,
   onComplete: function (response) {
      if (response.success == true) {
      }
       else {
       }

    }
});
```

If I submit form with clicking Submit button, there is no problem. But if I submit form with Enter Key, form validation and ajax request working together. So submit pass the validation.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't understand, does the validation not happen or it happens, but the form gets submitted anyway? Also, can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: Validation happens but not stop the submit. So ajax request is running also. But normally submit form by click Submit button, there is no problem. When submit form with Enter key, problem occurring.

Comment: Please create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with a full example (HTML as well), otherwise it's difficult to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ok, https://jsfiddle.net/so7jzpcz/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic UI adds a keyboard shortcut of its own that submits the form when you press enter, but this submission seems to bypass the validation mechanism for some reason. This might actually be a bug, so I'd [urge you to report it](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues).

That said, you can disable these shortcuts using `keyboardShortcuts: false` when you initialise the form:

```
$('.ui.form').form({
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    fields: {
       term: ['minLength[5]', 'empty']
    }
});
```

On most browsers, pressing enter will just submit the form, so this gives you the same effect as pressing the submit button.

Comment: After multiple bug reports about this, the maintainers of Semantic UI refuse to even acknowledge the problem. Apparently Fomantic UI has addressed and fixed the bug however. I'm beginning to this Fomantic UI is the better fork.